# Why are the changes that I made in a CSV file not saved?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

Why are the changes that I made in a CSV file not saved? For example, I change the style of a cell to "Numbers". I save the file, but when I open the file again, the changes aren't saved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSV files contain only data, as comma-separated values.  If you want to keep your formatting changes, save the file as an Excel file (i.e. myfile.xls), using the 'save as' file menu option.

Comment: Even more: I'm quite sure Excel warns about that when saving...?

Comment: Oddly (and unfortunately) not anymore for me.  Is there a setting?

Answer (score 3):

Because csv only contains data, not style. If you want to save style save as `.xls`.

Answer (score 3):

CSV files can't contain styling. Any styling you apply will only exist for that editing session.

If you want to preserve styling, save in a different format, such as XLS.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files contain only data.

You can ensure Excel helps prevent formatting loss with its automatic Save As dialogue box.  You can disable/re-enable the Save As box by going to File-->Options-->Save-->'Show data loss warning when editing comma delimited files'.